# "Cannot set property 'stopPropagation' of undefined" before loading the map

Tags: webpack, openlayers, openlayers-3

Whenever I connect to the app that uses openlayers 3.2.0 version and webpack for bundling I get the following error: **Cannot set property 'stopPropagation' of undefined**. You can see the chunk of the code that causes the error below. At first the error used to pop up from time to time and either logging out of google chrome(I guess it worked either thanks to clearing the cache or deleting extensions) or changing the browser helped to magically fix the issue, but it doesn't work anymore. Do you have any ideas as to what could be the cause of this error?

```
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

var proj4 = require('proj4');

(ol.proj as any).proj4_ = proj4;

(ol.events as any).Event.stopPropagation = function (evt) {
    if (!$(evt.target).hasClass("ol3-disable-stop") && $(evt.target).parents(".ol3-disable-stop-parent").length == 0) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        let e = new evt.constructor(evt.type, evt);
        document.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: "(ol.events as any).Event " this should be undefined.. recheck your initial code...

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: cool.... add your answer here that can help others too  :)